# TypeError while mocking using Python mock framework

Tags: python, mocking

I am getting TypeError takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given) while trying to mock a class function using python mock framework.

```
>>> class ExampleClass():
...     @staticmethod
...     def _process_updates(arg1, arg2):
...         pass
... 
>>> 
>>> @patch("ExampleClass._process_updates")
... def process_updates(arg1, arg2):
...   return "test"
... 
>>> ExampleClass._process_updates()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: _process_updates() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
>>>
```

Comment: How are you running that second snippet? The patch decorator only applies within the method it decorates; any other time you call `_process_updates`, the patch is not active and the original method is used.

Comment: I think you are missing a second argument in `process_updates` for the `MagicMock` the decorator sends in.

Comment: @DanielRoseman All this code is defined in the python console. The second snippet is run from the same python console in which the above mentioned code as already been written.

Comment: But as I say, this can't work. The patch decorator applies *within the function it decorates*. Outside that function, there is no patching.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have now edited the question to give clear picture. Please check. How can I make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes anything I've said. The method is only patched *within* the `process_updates` function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sure. I understood your comment now. Can you suggest any alternative way using which method patching can be retained?

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielRoseman said, `@patch` substitutes for a function (method) *used* by the function its patching. i.e. in the following example, the function `calling_func_with_mock` is the patched version of `calling_func` because we have substituted `process_updates` for `_process_updates` (within the local `ExampleClass` object).

I think they key for you is to patch the higher level function that is *using* `ExampleClass`. HTH

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class ExampleClass():
    @staticmethod
    def _process_updates(arg1, arg2):
        return arg1

def patched_process_updates(arg1, arg2):
    return arg2

def calling_func():
    """Uses normal ExampleClass._process_updates"""
    print( ExampleClass._process_updates('Hello','world') )

@patch('__main__.ExampleClass._process_updates', new=patched_process_updates)
def calling_func_with_mock():
    """Uses ExampleClass._process_updates patch"""
    print( ExampleClass._process_updates('Hello','world') )

if __name__=='__main__':
    calling_func()
    # 'Hello'
    calling_func_with_mock()
    # 'world'
```